# Prove that for all integers $a$, $b$ and $d$, if $d$ |$2a + b$ and $d$ | $3a + b$, then $d$ | $a$ and $d$ | $b$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I'm having trouble proving this statement. I've assumed $d | 2a + b$ and $d | 3a + b$ and then isolated $a$ on both equations and $b$ on both equations and I can't get any of these 4 to look like $a=dm$ for int m nor any counter examples. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Hint: $\,a = (3a+b)-(2a+b)\,$.

Comment: @dxiv Can i do the same thing for $b$, where $b = 2(2a+b) - (3a+b)$?

Comment: Well, $\,b \ne 2(2a+b) - (3a+b)\,$, but once you've got that $\,d \mid a\,$ and you know that $\,d \mid 2a+b\,$, then you can derive that $\,d \mid b\,$ directly.

Comment: @dxiv I can derive that by logic? Or is there more algebra involved?

Comment: $d \mid a \implies d \mid 2a\,$ and $d \mid 2a + b  \;\land\; d \mid 2a \implies d \mid (2a+b) - (2a) = b\,$.

Comment: Ah I see. Could I also do it the way i mentioned before, but with correct numbers this time(I am very tired) I.E. $b$ = $3(2a + b) - 2(3a+b)$? Thank you by the way.

Comment: Yes, that would work as well.